# journalctl only refreshing after restarting systemd service?

Tags: logging, systemd, daemon, gunicorn, journalctl

I have a systemd service with gunicorn. I have a print statement in a function.Problem is that, journalctl does not show the print output when i call the function but it shows the output after refresing the systemd service unit. Should it behave like this? What could be the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Python's default behavior to buffer stdin, stdout and stderr. For a systemd file, include the following line within the same block as `ExecStart=/path/to/gunicorn`.

`Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering for alternative ways to disable it.